# git ignorecase = false doesn't show deleted files

Tags: git

I've set git config to `false` and changed the case of a folder. When I'm doing `git status` it shows me a new file 'folder\somefile`, but doesn't show me that old files`Folder\somefile` is deleted. Why?

Comment: Which operating system are you using? Case handling is dependent on OS.

Comment: I'm using both Windows (for development) and Linux (for production). The behavior I'm facing is on Windows. And I'm not sure if the `ignorecase` should be set to `true` or `false` under the circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

`ignorecase` should be set to `true` whenever your filesystem doesn't strictly distinguish upper/lowercase. On Windows, the case of your filenames is *preserved*, but it's ignored when looking up files (i.e. the filesystem will return the same thing for both `folder` and `Folder`). So, setting `ignorecase` to `false` is probably not a good choice on Windows.

Comment: Thanks, can you elaborate on _setting ignorecase to false is probably not a good choice on Windows_? And what should I do I have git repos on both Windows and Linux, however active development takes place only on Windows?

Comment: Just set `ignorecase` to false on Linux (the default), and to true on Windows (should be done by default if you're using Git for Windows). And, well, what more is there to say about `ignorecase` on Windows than... if you set it to true, the thing you saw happens...? ;)

Comment: If it's set to FALSE on Windows, then git status doesn't pick any changes... anyways, I've done some research and found out that the best and the safest way to change case in a folder is to move the files out of the folder, commit deletion, change case of the folder name and move files back.

Comment: Whoops, sorry. I meant to say: "if you set it to *false*, the thing you saw happens." On Windows, more generally on non-case-sensitive filesystems, the only sane value is *true*.